Echarts labels z index is broken when Echarts has too much data per axis
I have a echarts project with multiple series-lines with multiples axis, I use axisPointer interactivity with all xAxisIndex for have emphasis data on all graphs. But the emphasis kill the label axis depth when there is too much data.
What I found is that when I suppress 6+ line of data, the labels z index work like expected.
I think Iam near the limit of echarts.
Anyone could confirm this issue ?
In default project:

When I remove 6+ data lines in datasets it work like expected:

This is the codesandbox project for test
The video showing labels issue
thanks
